# Use forms Maps and Geo-location

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using Xamarin.Forms.Maps with Xamarin.Essentials I receive the following error:

> Error CS0104 'Map' is an ambiguous reference between 'Xamarin.Essentials.Map' and 'Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map'

I want to be able to use a Map and view the location information when the user clicks their location.

My solution was to create a class which fetches the location information. The page which has the map has this code.

```
    public static double LatValue { set; get; } //Pass this to GeoLoc
    public static double LongValue { set; get; } //Pass this to GeoLoc
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var map = new Map(
        MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(22.4, -90.5), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
        };
        map.MapClicked += Map_MapClicked;
        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        Content = stack;
    }

    private void Map_MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        LatValue = e.Position.Latitude;
        LongValue = e.Position.Longitude;
        Console.WriteLine($"MapClick: {e.Position.Latitude}, {e.Position.Longitude}");
    }
```

The Geolocation has this class:

```
public async void GetGeosLoc()
    {
        try
        {
            var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(Page2.LatValue, Page2.LongValue);

            var placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
            if (placemark != null)
            {
                var geocodeAddress =
                    $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
                    $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
                    $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
                    $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
                    $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
                    $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
                    $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
                    $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
                    $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
                    $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

                Console.WriteLine(geocodeAddress);
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Feature not supported on device
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception that may have occurred in geocoding
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way round to using forms maps with essentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you have use the correct nuget packages

`Xamarin.Forms.Maps` and `Xamarin.Essentials`

I saw your error message is related to the `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map` not Xamarin.Forms.Maps`, please open your NuGet Package Manager, check the name of these nuget packages.
[image]

I test it in my emulator, I can use these nuget packages(`Xamarin.Forms.Maps` and `Xamarin.Essentials`) at the same time.

Here is my running screenshot.

[image]

In my code, I use `Xamarin.Essentials` get the location information, display the alert.

I post my code. you can refer to it(do not forget to replace value of the `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` in `AndroidManifest.xml`  )

https://github.com/851265601/MyMapdemo

Comment: Ah i was missing `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map` was obvious mistake, thank you.